# How to set redis express-session store with loopback?

Tags: node.js, redis, loopbackjs, express-session

I'm using loopback 3. Which connector is better **loopback-connect-redis** or **loopback-kv-redis** and how to configure store attribute in express-session object after adding the datasource?

I tried:
`store: app.dataSources.myDataSourceName` but I got an error

> "store.get is not a function"

so I tried:

```
store: app.dataSources.myDataSourceName).KeyValueAccessObject
```

I don't get any error but I don't have any key,value on redis. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Loopback (which I'm not hugely familiar with, admittedly) is based on Express (which I am familiar with).

I believe you should just use the `express-sessions` as in normal Express.

```
const 
  ...
  session     = require('express-session'),
  RedisStore  = require('connect-redis')(session),
  redis       = require('redis'),
  rs          = new RedisStore({ client  : redis.createClient([connection your info]) })
});

session({ 
  secret              : 'foobar',
  store               : rs
});
```

Then you would register it in your `middleware.json` file in the `session` phase.

Comment: Thank you but there is already a connector for loopback that's what I'm trying to use [Loopback-redis](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Redis-connector.html). and [Loopback-kv-redis](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/kv-redis-connector.html) I didn't understand the difference between them and how to use them in my project.
Also I wanted to know what is the difference between your code and this one : 
`const session = require('express-session');
RedisStore  = require('connect-redis')(session),
  rs          = new redisStore({host: '', port: }))`

Thank you

Comment: `express-session` is designed to work with `connect-redis` which is designed to work with `node_redis` (aka `require('redis')`). Loopback-redis and loopback-kv-redis have a different API and are designed as datasources for loopback specifically. They won't work with express-sessions.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how does it work when I don't use `require('redis')` and I can see my data on redis